# Variable name in a for loop while using subprocess.Popen() - Python

Tags: python, loops, variables, for-loop

I currently have written this Python code:

```
import subprocess, os, sys, tkFileDialog

path1 =  tkFileDialog.askdirectory(title='Choose the folder where the point clouds .ply are located')
print path1

filePoisson =  tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title='Choose PoissonRecon.exe')


for filename in os.listdir(path1):

    if filename.endswith(".ply") :

        subprocess.Popen(
            [
               filePoisson,
                "--in", "os.path.abspath(filename)",
                "--color", "16",
                "--depth", "9",
                "--out", "outputname.ply",
                "--density",
                "--samplesPerNode", "1.50",
                "--fullDepth", "5",
                "--pointWeight", "4",
                "--bType", "2"
            ]
        )

    else:
        continue

raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

So the first problem is here:

```
"--in", "os.path.abspath(filename)",
```

Here the PoissonRecon.exe wants the path of the first .ply file which is in the folder chosen as path1.
So, for example, something like "E:\\POISSON\\TEST\\firstFile.ply" is expected.
However, as I'm using a loop for, I don't know how to write this part of the code.

The second problem is almost similar:

```
"--out", "outputname.ply",
```

Here the PoissonRecon.exe only expects the output name.
For example, if the path of the variable path1 (where all the .ply files are located) is "E:\\POISSON\\TEST" then, the program will simply save the output file in this folder.

However I'd like to take the variable "filename" and add something like "_AFTER_POISSON.ply"

I hope everything is clear enough!
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Hi manny-, I am trying to understand your problem a little more. How is using a for loop restricting you?

Comment: Hi PrestonM, the loop for is not the "real" problem, my first problem is to be able to write the path of every file (for example: E:\\\POISSON\\\TEST\\\firstFile.ply)
For the second file, it would be E:\\\POISSON\\\TEST\\\secondFile.ply etc.
I guess I must use the filename variable combined with the path maybe ?
I'm new in Python scripting .. that's why I requested help :)

Comment: I see. Is there a reason for having "os.path.abspath(filename)" in quotes?

Comment: No, i have simply tried different tests. I think the quotes could be deleted

Answer (score 0):

you could use glob to find all the files that end with `.ply` and iterate through them, something like:

```
import glob, os
import tkFileDialog

path1 =  tkFileDialog.askdirectory(title='Choose the folder where the point clouds .ply are located')
print path1
filePoisson =  tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title='Choose PoissonRecon.exe')

for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(path1, '*.ply')):
    input_filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(f)), f)
    subprocess.Popen(
        [
           filePoisson,
            "--in", input_filename,
            "--color", "16",
            "--depth", "9",
            "--out", f[:-4] + '_AFTER_.ply',
            "--density",
            "--samplesPerNode", "1.50",
            "--fullDepth", "5",
            "--pointWeight", "4",
            "--bType", "2"
        ]
    )


raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

That will keep your filename intact, add the abs path for the input and replace the ending for the output.
For reference, `glob.glob('*.ply')` returns a list of all files with that extension.  Then `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(f))` finds the path to that file and we can combine for the input file.  `f[:-4]` takes the filename, removes the last 4 characters(`.ply`) and then we can add the ending we like.

Comment: Thanks Nick for your code.
I guess else: continue has nothing to do here ? (i'm getting an error, when i erase it no more error ^^)
However it worked perfectly !

Comment: Yes, sorry i left that in from the copy-paste, I have edited it, try that now!

Comment: I will expand my answer with an explanation too

Comment: Would `input_filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname, f)` not be helpful here? The first line in the loop is bothering me

Comment: @CharlieG, yes that would be a more elegant way of doing it, as the `'/'` would mean this would fail on windows.  Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Or substitute `os.path.abspath(f)` as the first param in `os.path.join`, whichever's right

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help :D @NickHale

Comment: Oops! Just tested it. `os.path.abspath(f)` is all you need. It gives you the full path. @NickHale

Comment: Nick, I have a question regarding glob.glob. It seems to only work if my python script .py is located in the same folder as the .ply files.

Is there a way to have the .py script on the desktop for example and still be able to run it ?

Comment: Sorry to disturb again.. 
But now with: input_filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname, f) it doesn't work anymore..

However, the command: input_filename = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filename)) + '/' + filename is working great.

But it is only working if the .py script file is located in the same folder as the .ply files. Do you understand why ?

Comment: have you seen my latest edit to the code i posted?  where i have put `glob.glob(os.join(path1, '*.ply')` that will ensure that the path you choose for path1 is the folder that glob will look in.

Comment: oh... i didn't notice this. Is " ) " missing at the end? glob.glob(os.join(path1, '*.ply')

Comment: well spotted!  I've just edited that.  Does it help?

Comment: No .. The program closes automatically. I think it doesnt detect any .ply file. Maybe I should try something like:     for f in glob.glob(os.join(path1+ '/' + '*.ply')): ?

Comment: that might be simpler as `glob.glob(path1 + '/*.ply')`

Comment: Still not working.. I have to go right now. I'll try tomorrow again and keep you informed. Otherwise I'll use the previous version which worked, even though the script has the be in the same directory as the files.

Comment: @manny- I have made some edits and tested it, this now should work from whatever directory you start in.  Hope this solves it for you

Comment: @NickHale, I've just tested the script, it seems to work perfectly right now! Thank you very much :)